# Read response in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using simplest code of Jquery to check if the request is made to server to check certain table column and return true or false accordingly....

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_ajax_availablity.php",
        data: "user_name=" + user_name,

        success: function (server_response) {
            alert(server_response);                                
        }
    });
```

My PHP script is ...

```
<?php
    include 'admin_functions.php';
    if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
        $user_name = $_REQUEST['user_name'];
        $condition = " `UserName` = '" . $user_name . "'";
        $result = $oAdmFun->chk_records('login_admin', $condition);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            return "N";
        } else {
            return "Y";
        }
    }
?>
```

Issue is its alerting blank value...

Comment: Check in the console for errors (press F12)

Comment: What happens when you pull up the PHP page by itself, without AJAX?

Comment: @Jake : Its alerting undefined on using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `return "N"` and `return "Y"`, try using `echo "N"` and `echo "Y"`.

Comment: Actually we are calling the function using ajax.You have to echo the out put if you are calling function using ajax.
If you are calling functions within php then there you have to return the output to function.But ajax treat function call differently than PHP

Comment: Just a clarification: it's not that AJAX threats calls differently; what you need on your client is the _output_ provided by your php code, not the _result_ that such code would return to some hypotethical server side call. As a rule of thumb, you should check your expected output by calling directly the php page on your browser (that's what I do in most cases), and you should output the desired result with `echo`, as @Hemantxp stated.